How to return optional regex groups from long string?
I wanted to say thank you to all help so far just from referencing all the help from you guys on here. Thank you.
I am starting a new position in my job and it involves a ton of regex(which I am new to). I came across a pretty complex use case and needed to know what to do. I am trying to pull multiple groups from a text file and then I'm going to use them as a table.(using UIpath) Here is my example text using regex101.com (.net/c#)
Earn Rate / Current YTD Tax W-4 Current YTD Ded Current YTD Desc Amount
Name Amount Hrs Amount Hrs Amount Name Amount Amount Name Amount Amount

Jacobs, Glenn
Emp: 9 REG 25.00 80.00 2,000.00 469.00 11,725.00 FWT M 0 61.33 393.09 HLTH PT 123.66 550.62 Net 1,465.00
PTOHRLY 11.00 275.00 SSEE 115.09 706.14 HLTH ER 115.38 721.14 Deposited 1,465.00
MEDCEE 26.92 165.15 401K % 120.00 720.00
COWT M 0 59.00 366.00 401KER 80.00 480.00 Voucher No. 137
CODENVEE 17.25 HSA 20.00 60.00
COFAMEE 9.00 54.00
QTD Gross: 12,000.00 Gross: 80.00 2,000.00 480.00 12,000.00 271.34 EE Deds: 263.66

Wight, Paul Q
Emp: 11 DAYS 525.00 8.00 4,200.00 12.00 6,300.00 FWT M 0 751.38 1,250.76 Net 2,940.42
SSEE 260.40 390.60 Deposited 2,940.42
MEDCEE 60.90 91.35
COWT M 0 168.00 243.00 Voucher No. 138
CODENVEE 5.75
COFAMEE 18.90 28.35
QTD Gross: 6,300.00 Gross: 8.00 4,200.00 12.00 6,300.00 1,259.58

Johnson, Dwayne A
Emp: 6 REG 22.00 80.00 1,760.00 472.00 10,384.00 FWT S 0 105.43 706.72 HLTH PT 139.96 842.10 Net 1,219.16
OT1.5 20.00 660.00 SSEE 100.44 643.41 HLTH ER 115.38 721.14 Deposited 1,219.16
PTOHRLY 8.00 176.00 MEDCEE 23.49 150.48 401K % 105.60 673.20
COWT S 0 58.00 375.00 401KER 70.40 448.80 Voucher No. 139
CODENVEE 17.25
COFAMEE 7.92 50.49
QTD Gross: 11,220.00 Gross: 80.00 1,760.00 500.00 11,220.00 295.28 EE Deds: 245.56

The text is from a PDF generated to txt. It has much more in it but I tried to make it look nice here. I added new lines before the names just so it easier to read here.
My regex argument is:
(\w+),\s(\w+.*(\n(?=Emp:))).*\n.*\n.*\n.*((?<=401KER\s)\d*\.\d*)?.*\n.*\n.*\n.*((?<=Gross:\s\d*\.*\d*\s)\d*\,*\d*\.*\d+)

It captures all the groups I want but I want the middle group (401KER) to be optional. I placed a ? at the end of the group and it selects all 3 people but excludes the group from the other 2 that have the (401K) group. I am trying to make a table that has all 3 people and the one that doesn't have 401K to just return a 0 or something that at least leaves a blank cell value to work with.

See https://regex101.com/r/i2wfWt/1. I did not touch the rest of the logic.

You got it! I feel kind of dumb but is it just because I had the "." in front and behind the middle group? I saw you included the first one inside the () and the second one outside after the "optional ?". Essentially, was I looking for too many "."? Also, Thank you for showing me a cleaner way of writing those repetitive line breaks and whatnot.

This pattern isn't clean at all (because of many useless things in particular). If you want something clean see that commented pattern: https://regex101.com/r/YiKvz5/1

You can use
(\w+),\s(\w.*(\n))Emp:(?:.+\n){3}(?:.*401KER\s(\d*\.\d*))?.*(?:\n.*){3}Gross:\s\d*\.*\d*\s(\d*\,*\d*\.*\d+)

See the regex demo.
Details:

(\w+) - Group 1: one or more word chars
,\s - a comma and then a whitespace
(\w.*(\n)) - Group 2: a word char and then the rest of the line with the LF char (that is captured into Group 3)
Emp: - an Emp: substring
(?:.+\n){3} - three lines (note that we do not even need \r? before \n as in .NET . matches CR symbols)
(?:.*401KER\s(\d*\.\d*))? - an optional sequence of

.* - any zero or more chars other than a newline char as many as possible
401KER - a substring
\s - a whitespace
(\d*\.\d*) - Group 4: zero or more digits, ., zero or more digits


.* - the rest of the 4th line
(?:\n.*){3} - three lines
Gross: - Gross: substring
\s - a whitespace
\d*\.*\d* - zero or more digits, ., zero or more digits
\s - a whitespace
(\d*,*\d*\.*\d+) - Group 5: zero or more digits, zero or more commas, zero or more digits, zero or more dots, one or more digits.

If you are sure the matches start at the beginning of a line add (?m)^ at the start of the pattern:
(?m)^(\w+),\s(\w.*(\n))Emp:(?:.+\n){3}(?:.*401KER\s(\d*\.\d*))?.*(?:\n.*){3}Gross:\s\d*\.*\d*\s(\d*\,*\d*\.*\d+)

You may - if your UI is friendly enough - describe the pattern using the (?x) flag, something like
(?xm)^ # RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace and RegexOptions.Multiline on, start of a line
(\w+) # Group 1: ....
etc.

Remember, in this mode, you will need to escape literal whitespaces and # chars.
